# Is passing self to a method call in class consider as circular dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I stumble upon this python code with this structure.

```
class A():
     def method1(self):
          B().method3(self)
```

```
    def method2(self, str):
         print(str)
```

class B():
     def method3(self, a):
         a.method2("Hello World")

A().method1()

By passing `self` of `A`to `B`, is this some kind of circular dependency? Or it is some kind of highly adopted and common design practice in python?

Comment: What is `B().("Hello World", self)` meant to do?

Comment: Opps, I fix the code now. My bad

Comment: Now it's at least readable... No, it's not a circular dependency, it's a sign that whoever wrote that structure should not be let anywhere near a keyboard, and if you've seen that in some module - do not use that module. What it essentially does is create an instance of `B` just so it can call its `method3()` method, which will in turn call a `method2()` method on the passed (presumably caller) instance.

Comment: A circular dependency is when object A holds a reference to object B, and B also holds a reference to A.  This is neither a circular dependency or a highly adopted and common design practice.  It's just a ridiculous piece of code.

Comment: Actually the original code is not that simple, basically what it did is `A` is being passed to `B` in one of the method in `B` and `B` did a lots of operation and changes on the instance variable of `A` by calling method in A. But I assume it's still a bad practice and crap to write code in this way.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far.  In any useful program the objects have to interact with each other.  It's good practice to keep it to a minimum, and it's best if it only goes in one direction (B creates an instance of A and calls methods in A but not vice versa).  Proper object-oriented design isn't easy, and in my experience it's impossible to achieve perfection in this area.  I would recommend the book "Clean Code" for a modern take on this problem, and although it's written for Java developers I still found it very insightful.

Comment: This sounds like double dispatch to me, see here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch